# I made dedicated server in UE4 and I need help for work this server in vds server

Tags: server, unreal-engine4, multiplayer, unreal-blueprint, dedicated-server

I made a dedicated server in ue4.27 as I said in title. Then i runned server by local host. I used my pc and I used console in debug. `open 127.0.0.1` That was my code. Then I rented a vds server. I tried `open (IP)`after run server in vds. and it didnt work. My question is how can use this vds as server and what got to do for join. (I successfully made ded server and it worked on my local host Im asking for vds) (I successfully runned my server şn vds but I couldnt join from my pc's debug.) (you guys can give me code as bp in ue4) (because problem is in the ue4 project.)

I tried do this as local host (because in local host you just opening server as -log and you can see the logs. when you write `open 127.0.0.1` in debug system in your own  pc its works. But when i tried to do this in vds server, it didnt work. (yes guys I used vds's IP instead 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that this could be because you have not opened the necessary ports (usually defaulted to 7777, 7778 and 7779 for an Unreal Engine dedicated server) on your VDS, how you do this will depend on the operating system installed on your VDS, I recommend checking that first.